# difference between _app.js and document.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I downloaded html css template and trying to integrate in "nextjs". What is difference between "_app.js" and "document.js"? where should i use/include "css, js" files? either in "_app.js" or inside "document.js" ?

Answer (score 2):

As [nextJS docs specify](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) related to `_app.js`:

> Next.js uses the App component to initialize pages. You can override it and control the page initialization and:
>
> - Persist layouts between page changes
> - Keeping state when navigating pages
> - Custom error handling using componentDidCatch
> - Inject additional data into pages
> - Add global CSS

[Next page of the docs also specify](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) that `_document.js` is:

> A custom Document can update the  and  tags used to render
> a Page. This file is only rendered on the server, so event handlers
> like onClick cannot be used in _document.

So basically your global css should go in App.js. However if you need to import certain CDN styles for some libraries I suppose you can do that here as well (but you should probably consider using just `_app.js` for this as well as it can be seen in [this example](https://medium.com/nextjs/how-to-use-bootstrap-5-with-cdn-in-nextjs-e9b9c8fd35cd))

---

Regarding the JS question as wikipedia states:

> Next.js is an open-source web development framework created by Vercel enabling React-based web applications with server-side rendering and generating static websites.

So basically you should import React components where you need them, but I would recommend you to follow a tutorial if you need to learn more about React (There are a lot of beginner NextJS tutorials that can cover this).

Comment: so me should put my css and js files inside "_app.js" ? am i right ?

Comment: For most cases, and if we are talking about generic css and js files,  yes